# Prestashop 1.7 hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateBefore and after

Tags: hook, smarty, prestashop-1.7

So, I'm wondering why if I put a variable (public) in the hook hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateBefore and read it, then in the hook hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateAfter I lose it. Even if I assign it as smarty variable.

I'm running these hooks from a module and in backend.

Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

To add a public variable on Customer class, you should override this class and add your custom variable. then you can use it every where on PrestaShop.
You can't use "action hooks" to add new definitions to PrestaShop. these hooks are made just for the actions.

Comment: Ok I already have a customer override to use. But, if I use hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateAfter, for example, for calling my function in customer where I assign my smarty variable Customer::get_client_activebefore($customer->active); this variable is empty if I try to read it for example in hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateAfter. so, how do I access the data?

Comment: Well, I understand that these hooks are invisible and therefore they do not access any kind of variable. Perhaps the only solution is to save what I need in db.